# Problem in fetch of a json server in react

Tags: reactjs, json, server

VM543:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
I have problem at fetch of json server that i made alone .The server is correct

Comment: seems the response is not a valid json instead it does return some html ...

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.

You are trying to parse json from your response (string). something like `JSON.parse('<!doctype html...')`

**Your server is not returning an application/json data**